# Неправильная работа фильтра на сайте

Tags: javascript

У меня такая проблема, сделал свой первый сайт ves-shiny.ru, и как недавно выяснил сделал не так как хотел. В чем суть, при выборе в "Производитель" и нажав на кнопку "Выбрать" появятся шины выбранного производителя (летние, зимние, шипованные и нешипованные) вроде все нормально, но после того как пользователь захочет отсортировать с помощью "Check-box" (показать только летние или только шипованные), то к выбранному производителю добавляются все остальные производители. А я хочу чтобы "Chek-box" отрабатывали только с выбранным производителем. Как я понял моя ошибка в том, что я просто вывел все шины на страницу и скрыл их командой JS "Hide", а после нажатия на кнопку "Выбрать" срабатывает команда "Show". Вообщем вопрос как организовать, чтобы все работало правильно, буду благодарен любой помощи.

```
<form>

                            <label>
                                <span>Производитель</span>
                                <select id="brend">
                                    <option disabled selected>Все</option>
                                    <option value="Continental">Continental</option>
                                    <option value="Dunlop">Dunlop</option>
                                    <option value="Firestone">Firestone</option>
                                    <option value="Formula">Formula</option>
                                    <option value="GeneralTire">GeneralTire</option>
                                    <option value="Gislaved">Gislaved</option>
                                    <option value="Goform">Goform</option>
                                    <option value="Goodrich">Goodrich</option>
                                    <option value="GoodYear">GoodYear</option>
                                    <option value="Hankook">Hankook</option>
                                    <option value="Headway">Headway</option>
                                    <option value="Horizon">Horizon</option>
                                    <option value="Kama">Kama</option>
                                    <option value="Kumho">Kumho</option>
                                    <option value="Laufenn">Laufenn</option>
                                    <option value="Matador">Matador</option>
                                    <option value="Maxxis">Maxxis</option>
                                    <option value="Michelin">Michelin</option>
                                    <option value="Nitto">Nitto</option>
                                    <option value="Nokian">Nokian</option>
                                    <option value="Pirelli">Pirelli</option>
                                    <option value="Sailun">Sailun</option>
                                    <option value="Sava">Sava</option>
                                    <option value="Tigar">Tigar</option>
                                    <option value="ToyoTires">ToyoTires</option>
                                    <option value="Viatti">Viatti</option>
                                    <option value="Yokohama">Yokohama</option>

                                </select>
                            </label>

                            <label>
                                <span>Ширина</span>
                                <select id="width">
                                    <option disabled selected>Все</option>
                                    <option value="115">115</option>
                                    <option value="125">125</option>
                                    <option value="135">135</option>
                                    <option value="145">145</option>
                                    <option value="155">155</option>
                                    <option value="165">165</option>
                                    <option value="175">175</option>
                                    <option value="185">185</option>
                                    <option value="195">195</option>
                                    <option value="205">205</option>
                                    <option value="215">215</option>
                                    <option value="225">225</option>
                                    <option value="235">235</option>
                                    <option value="245">245</option>
                                    <option value="255">255</option>
                                    <option value="265">265</option>
                                    <option value="275">275</option>
                                    <option value="285">285</option>
                                    <option value="295">295</option>
                                    <option value="305">305</option>
                                    <option value="315">315</option>
                                    <option value="325">325</option>
                                    <option value="335">335</option>
                                    <option value="345">345</option>

                                </select>
                            </label>

                            <label>
                                <span>Высота</span>
                                <select id="height">
                                    <option disabled selected>Все</option>
                                    <option value="25">25</option>
                                    <option value="27">27</option>
                                    <option value="29">29</option>
                                    <option value="30">30</option>
                                    <option value="31">31</option>
                                    <option value="32">32</option>
                                    <option value="33">33</option>
                                    <option value="34">34</option>
                                    <option value="35">35</option>
                                    <option value="36">36</option>
                                    <option value="37">37</option>
                                    <option value="38.5">38.5</option>
                                    <option value="40">40</option>
                                    <option value="42">42</option>
                                    <option value="45">45</option>
                                    <option value="50">50</option>
                                    <option value="55">55</option>
                                    <option value="60">60</option>
                                    <option value="65">65</option>
                                    <option value="70">70</option>
                                    <option value="75">75</option>
                                    <option value="80">80</option>
                                    <option value="82">82</option>
                                    <option value="85">85</option>
                                    <option value="90">90</option>

                                </select>
                            </label>

                            <label>
                                <span>Диаметр</span>
                                <select id="diametr">
                                    <option disabled selected>Все</option>
                                    <option value="12">12</option>
                                    <option value="12C">12C</option>
                                    <option value="13">13</option>
                                    <option value="13C">13C</option>
                                    <option value="14">14</option>
                                    <option value="14C">14C</option>
                                    <option value="15">15</option>
                                    <option value="15C">15C</option>
                                    <option value="16">16</option>
                                    <option value="16C">16C</option>
                                    <option value="17">17</option>
                                    <option value="17C">17C</option>
                                    <option value="18">18</option>
                                    <option value="18C">18C</option>
                                    <option value="19">19</option>
                                    <option value="20">20</option>
                                    <option value="21">21</option>
                                    <option value="22">22</option>
                                    <option value="23">23</option>

                                </select>
                            </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 clearfix">

                            <div class="leto">
                                <input class="check-box" type="checkbox" id="leto" />
                                <label class="check" for="leto">Летняя<img src="img/solnce.png" alt="solnce"></label>

                            </div>

                            <div class="zima">
                                <input class="check-box" type="checkbox" id="zima" />
                                <label class="check" for="zima">Зимняя<img src="img/snezhinka.png" alt="snezhinka"></label>
                            </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 clearfix">

                            <div class="ship">
                                <input class="check-box" type="checkbox" id="ship" />
                                <label class="check" for="ship">Шипованная<img src="img/shipovka.png" alt="shipovka"></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="neship">
                                <input class="check-box" type="checkbox" id="neship" />
                                <label class="check" for="neship">Нешипованная<img src="img/neshipovka.png" alt="shipovka"></label>
                            </div>
                            <button type="reset" class="button-right">Сбросить</button> 

            </div>
        </form>
        <button class="button-left" disabled>Выбрать</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


 function init() {
    $.post(
        "core.php",
        {
            "action" : "init"
        },
        vesShiny
    );
}

    function vesShiny(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            var out = '';
            for (var key in data){
                out+='<div class="cart ' + data[key] ['season'] + ' ' + data[key] ['ship'] + '" data-brend="' + data[key] ['brend'] + '" data-width="' + data[key] ['width'] + '" data-height="' + data[key] ['height'] + '" data-diametr="' + data[key] ['diametr'] + '" data-weight="' + data[key] ['weight'] + '" id="cart">';
                out+='<img src="' + data[key].image +'">';
                out+='<p class="brend"><b>' + data[key] ['brend'] + '</b></p>';
                out+='<p class="name"><b>' + data[key] ['name'] + '</b></p>';
                out+='<p class="width"><b>Ширина:  ' + data[key] ['width'] + '</span></b></p>';
                out+='<p class="height"><b>Высота:  ' + data[key] ['height'] + '</span></b></p>';
                out+='<p class="diametr"><b>Диаметр:  ' + data[key] ['diametr'] + '</span></b></p>';
                out+='<p class="season"><b>Сезон:  ' + data[key] ['season'] + '</span></b></p>';
                out+='<p class="weight"><b>Вес:  ' + data[key] ['weight'] + ' кг.</span></b></p>';
                out+='</div>';
            }
                $('.carts').html(out);
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    init();
});


                $('document').ready(function(){
                    $('.button-left').click(function(){
                        let carts = document.querySelector('.carts');

                        for (let i = 0; i < carts.children.length; i++) {
                            for (let j = i; j < carts.children.length; j++) {
                                if (+carts.children[i].getAttribute('data-weight') > +carts.children[j].getAttribute('data-weight')) {
                                    replacedNode = carts.replaceChild(carts.children[j], carts.children[i]);
                                    insertAfter(replacedNode, carts.children[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    });
                    function insertAfter(elem, refElem) {
                        return refElem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, refElem.nextSibling);
                    }


var brend_el = document.getElementById('brend');
var width_el = document.getElementById('width');
var height_el = document.getElementById('height');
var diametr_el = document.getElementById('diametr');
var carts_el = document.getElementById('carts');

var filter = function() {
        var carts = carts_el.getElementsByClassName('cart');

        for (var i = 0; i < carts.length; i++) {
                if ((brend_el.value == 'Все' || brend_el.value == cart[i].dataset.brend)&&
                    (width_el.value == 'Все' || width_el.value == cart[i].dataset.width) &&
                    (height_el.value == 'Все' || height_el.value == cart[i].dataset.height) &&
                    (diametr_el.value == 'Все' || diametr_el.value == cart[i].dataset.diametr)) {

                        cart[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
                } else {
                        cart[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
        }
    };

var el = document.getElementById('carts');
    if (null !== el) {
        brend_el.addEventListener("change", filter);
        width_el.addEventListener("change", filter);
        height_el.addEventListener("change", filter);
        diametr_el.addEventListener("change", filter);
    }

$('#zima').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('.summer').stop().hide();
    } else {
            $('.summer').stop().show();
    }
});

$('#leto').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('.winter').stop().hide();
    } else {
            $('.winter').stop().show();
    }
});

$('#ship').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('.0').stop().hide();
            $('.summer').stop().hide();
    } else {
            $('.1').stop().show();
            $('.0').stop().show();
            $('.summer').stop().hide();
    }
});

$('#neship').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('.1').stop().hide();
            $('.summer').stop().hide();
    } else {
            $('.0').stop().show();
            $('.1').stop().show();
            $('.summer').stop().hide();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#brend').on('change', function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $('.button-left').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('.button-left').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.button-left').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }
    });
})



$('.button-left').click (function() {
    $('.carts').show();
});


$('.button-right').click (function() {
    var del = $('.carts');
    del.detach().stop();
    del.appendTo('.result');
    $('.button-left').prop('disabled', true);
    $('.button-left').css('cursor', 'no-drop');
    $('.carts').hide();
});
```

Comment: Такого рода вещи всегда лучше получать отдельно, или же из JSON файлов или же через POST из PHP по требованию. Как минимум - google page speed вас заминусит, там есть пункт о том, чтобы соблюдалось ограниченное количество вложенности в элементах HTML при загрузке страницы http://joxi.ru/Dr8PM11codPqzr

Comment: А как  можно реализовать через POST из PHP по требованию ?

Comment: Вам @Skywave ответил, там в `ajax` можете добавить метод `POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я предпочитаю делать один метод, который занимается фильтрацией, например

```
function filterItems() {
    var filter = $('.filter'),
        items = $('.item');
    items.hide(); // скрываем все
    items.each(function(){
        if (checkItemFilter($(this), filter)) { // некий метод, который сможет определить проходит элемент по фильтру или нет
            $(this).show();
        }
    });

    // или может быть вы решите подгружать данные с сервера в зависимости от фильтра
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get-items.php',
        data: filter.serialize(),
        success: function(responseHtml){
            $('.items-container').html(responseHtml);
        }
    });
}
```

И дергать этот метод при каждом изменении фильтра и при загрузке страницы

```
filterItems();
$('.filter input, .filter select').on('change', function(){
    filterItems();
});
```

Таким образом фильтр всегда будет работать одинаково независимо от действий (чек, нажатие на кнопку, выбор чегонибудь)

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю логику Вашего фильтра в отношении "Select", как это должно работать?

Comment: @Maccan, Ну он либо показывает отфильтрованные объекты на странице, либо запрашивает их через ajax

Comment: ,Я не могу понять куда в моем случае ставить класс .filter,.filter input и .filter select.

Comment: `.filter` - контейнер, содержащий поля с филтрацией, в вашем примере им может быть `form`. Ну и `input` и `select` - поля внутри

Comment: А checkItemFilter ?